# join and group by query works in firebird 2.1 but not in 1.5

Tags: sql, firebird

I have the following query that works fine in firebird 2.1, however I cannot get it to work on a db with the exact same structure in 1.5

```
select c.printchecknumber, v.voidamount 
from checks c 
join (select checknumber, sum(voidamount) as voidamount 
      from checkitem 
      where voidtype =1 
      group by checknumber) v on c.checknumber = v.checknumber 
order by c.printchecknumber
```

Any ideas?

The error message is
Invalid token
Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 1, char 61
the error is at the start of the second select

Comment: this sql looks fine.  do you get a specific error message?

Comment: Derived tables were added in firebird 2: http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/rlsnotes207.html#dml-dsql-derived-tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that Firebird 1.5 doesn't support subqueries in the `from` clause.  In any case, you can write this as a simpler query.  The following should do what you want:

```
select c.printchecknumber, sum(voidamount) as voidamount 
from checkitem ci join
     checks c
     on ci.checknumber = c.checknumber
where ci.voidtype =1 
group by c.printchecknumber;
```

EDIT:

If you want to include `checkid`, then this might work:

```
select c.printchecknumber, c.checkid, sum(voidamount) as voidamount 
from checkitem ci join
     checks c
     on ci.checknumber = c.checknumber
where ci.voidtype =1 
group by c.printchecknumber, c.checkid;
```

Comment: That seems to work just fine, thank you for the help.
There is an additional column in the table checks called checkid
this column is not in the checkitem table and if i modify as
select c.checkid, c.printchecknumber, sum(void......
it says "invalid expression in the select list"

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it does not work on an earlier system and I'd need to know the error message to help, but the following would work on any sql which supports the over() clause which I believe firebird does with 3.0

```
select c.printchecknumber,
       sum(v.voidamount) over (partition by printchecknumber)
from checks c
join checkitem v on c.checknumber = v.checknumber and v.voidtype = 1
```

Comment: Windows functions will only be available in the upcoming Firebird 3.0 release (which has been "upcoming" for 3 years now...)

Comment: The second alpha for firebird 3 is going to be released this week.